# How to group data and build a stacked barchart with C# and Blazor ApexCharts?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, blazor, apexcharts

I am using Blazor with Blazor Apex Charts to make charts for the dashboard I am working on.
Now I have run into a bit of a problem.

The web-app is period based. By that i mean its only showing data from the selected period and back in time. One period is one month. Periods are denoted as an int, like: 202302, 202401 and so on.

I need a stacked barchart. Each bar is stacked showing the reveneue for each project type. The data in the chart starts at the selected period and goes back to the first month that year. It should be able to compare it to the same months in the previous year. In my dataset there is a possibility for the project types not being the same each month. 202301 and 202401 doesnt need to have the same project types.

What its supposed to look like:

[image: Example chart]

When i look at the documentation(https://apexcharts.github.io/Blazor-ApexCharts/bar-charts), each stack has its own ApexPointSeries and its referencing different properties. In my example the y-axis will allways be revenue, but for different project types.

Code behind:

```cs
 [Inject]
 AppData appData { get; set; }
 [Parameter]
 public List<ProjectReport> chartDataForStack { get; set; }

private List<RevenueProjectType> testStack = new List<RevenueProjectType>();
private ApexChartOptions<RevenueProjectType> options;

protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    options = new ApexChartOptions<RevenueProjectType>
    {
        Chart = new Chart
        {
            Stacked = true,

        },
        PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
        {
            Bar = new PlotOptionsBar
            {
                Horizontal = false
            }
        },
    };


    SortData();
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
public void SortData()
{
    //chartDataForStack is already sorted by some parameters before being passed to this component. Most notably the first possible month is selectedYear
    var selectedYear = appData.SelectedPeriod / 100;

    var testData = chartDataForStack.Where(x => x.type == "revenue")
        .GroupBy(g => g.period)
        .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
        .ToList();

    var thisYear = new List<IGrouping<int, ProjectReport>>();
    var lastYear = new List<IGrouping<int, ProjectReport>>();

    testGroup2 = new List<RevenueProjectType>();

    foreach (var group in testData)
    {
        if (group.Key / 100 == selectedYear)
        {
            thisYear.Add(group);
        }
        else if (group.Key % 100 <= appData.SelectedPeriod % 100)
        {
            lastYear.Add(group);
        }

    }

   
    foreach (var group in thisYear)
    {
        var temp = group.GroupBy(x => x.project_type).ToList();
        testGroup.AddRange(temp);
    }

    foreach (var item in testGroup)
    {
        var revProjType = new RevenueProjectType();
        revProjType.revenue = item.Sum(x => x.acc);
        revProjType.projectType = item.Key;
        revProjType.period = item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.period != 0).period.ConvertRawPeriod();
        testStack.Add(revProjType);
    }
```

cshtml:

```
<ApexChart TItem="RevenueProjectType"
           Title="Test"
           Options=options>
    @foreach(var item in testStack)
    {
        <ApexPointSeries TItem="RevenueProjectType"
                         Items="@testStack"
                         Name="@item.projectType"
                         SeriesType="SeriesType.Bar"
                         XValue="@(e => e.period)"
                         YAggregate="@(e => e.Sum(e => e.revenue))"
                         ShowDataLabels />
    }
    
 </ApexChart>
```

RevenueChartItem:

```cs
public class RevenueProjectType
{
    public string projectType { get; set; }
    public string period { get; set; }
    public decimal? revenue {  get; set; }
    public string projectTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

In my code example the list testStack seems to contain one entry for each project type for each period, with the summed revenue.
In the provided code I am just trying to get the current year in a stacked barchart, to maybe get some understanding as to how i would do this. The current code does stack the barcharts but the data in the chart is wrong.

Any help or pointers is much appreciated.